# How do I get a list of attribute values from a list of class instances

Tags: python, list, class

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self,name,health):
        self.name=name
        self.health=health

wolf=Enemy('wolf',100)
imp=Enemy('imp',70)
orc=Enemy('orc',130)
enemyList=[wolf,imp,orc]

while 1:
    enemyNumber=int(input("How many enemies are there? "))
    if enemyNumber in range(1,4):
        break
    else:
        print('Wrong number')

if enemyNumber<=2:
    del enemyList[2]
    if enemyNumber==1:
        del enemyList[1]
```

Basically what I want now is to be able to say something like:

```
attackTarget=None
while not attackTarget in enemyList:
        attackTarget=input('Which enemy do you want to attack? ')
        if not attackTarget in enemyList:
            wrongChoice()
```

The problem is that I don't have a list of the enemy names, but the instances themselves. I know I can get it with something like:

```
enemyNameList=[]
for i in range (enemyNumber):
    enemyNameList.append(enemyList[i].name)
```

but isn't there a simpler way that can be used in the while and if statements without creating a whole new permanent list? Something like enemyList.name

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
enemeyNameList = [enemy.name for enemy in List]
```

This still creates a whole new list, but does so more concissely.

If you try to do it without creating a new list, you may run into different sorts of inefficiencies.  Since you're testing repeatedly in the while loop, it makes sense to store the list of names.  Otherwise, you have to look up each enemy's name again and again on every pass through the loop.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. A little side question if I may: I noticed you wrote both the 'enemy's in the brackets with lower case and tried it with both lower and upper and it worked fine. So how does this happen? Nowhere in the code is lower case enemy even mentioned and I thought those things were case sensitive. If I try something like `goblin=enemy('goblin',150)` it gives a `NameError: name 'enemy' is not defined`.

Comment: @user3874806: The list comprehension defines it as a new variable.  See [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for examples, and you can google "Python list comprehension" for tons more info.